# django positiveinteger default value of blank

Tags: django, django-models, default

I have a models class with a select list / positive integer field.

```
class AchievementDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT = 1
    COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 2
    PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 3
    PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 4
    SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT = 5
    OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE = 6

ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES = (
    (ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Academic Details')),
    (COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Commercial Achievement')),
    (PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Personal Achievement')),
    (PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Professional Achievement')),
    (SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Sporting Achievement')),
    (OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, _('Other Achievement Type')),
)

....
achievement_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES)
....
```

The above set up adds in the following select list option as the default option:

```
<option value="">---------</option>
```

I have been instructed not to include **SELECT_TYPE = ''** into the ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES.

I am using [django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley) for client side validation, so the option value must be a blank value.

I have two questions:

**1. How do I replace the default text of '---------' with 'Select Achievement Type'**

**2. How do I remove the default option value when the form is in the edit template?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using the:

```
validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
```

This is how I used it:

Include the import in the models.py file:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
```

Include the types with the zero value included to the models.py file:

```
SELECT_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE = 0
ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT = 1
COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 2
PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 3
PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 4
SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT = 5
OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE = 6
WRITE_MY_OWN_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 7777  # 7777 triggers a hidden text field to be displayed.
DISPLAY_ONLY_ACHIEVEMENT_DESCRIPTION_WITH_PROMPT = 8888
DISPLAY_ONLY_ACHIEVEMENT_DESCRIPTION_WITHOUT_PROMPT = 9999

ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES = (
    (SELECT_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, _('Select Type')),
    (ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Academic Achievement')),
    (COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Commercial Achievement')),
    (PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Personal Achievement')),
    (PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Professional Achievement')),
    (SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Sporting Achievement')),
    (OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, _('Other Achievement Type')),
    (WRITE_MY_OWN_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, _('Write my own Type description')),
    (DISPLAY_ONLY_ACHIEVEMENT_DESCRIPTION_WITH_PROMPT, _('Display only Description with prompt')),
    (DISPLAY_ONLY_ACHIEVEMENT_DESCRIPTION_WITHOUT_PROMPT, _('Display only Description without prompt'))
)
```

Include the field in the models.py file with the choices, default and MinValueValidator:

```
 ....
 achievement_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES, default=SELECT_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
 ....
```

In the forms.py file, include the error_messages meta data to override the error message (for Django 1.5+):

```
    .....
    error_messages = {
        'achievement_type': {'validate_min': _('This field is required.')},
    }
    ....
```